# Evaluating double integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, area

$\int\int{xy(x+y)}dxdy$ over the area bounded by $y=x^2$ and $y=x$.
I tried like this:
$$\begin{align}\\
&\int_{x=0}^{x=1}\int_{y=x^2}^{y=x}xy(x+y)dydx\\
&=\int_{x=0}^{x=1}\int_{y=x^2}^{y=x}x^2ydydx+\int_{x=0}^{x=1}\int_{y=x^2}^{y=x}xy^2dydx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{x=0}^{x=1}x^2\left[y^2\right]_{x^2}^xdx+\frac{1}{3}\int_{x=0}^{x=1}x\left[y^3\right]_{x^2}^xdx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1x^2(x^2-x^4)dx+\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1x(x^3-x^6)dx\\
&\begin{aligned}\\
=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1x^4dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1x^6dx+\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1x^4dx-\frac{1}{3}&\int_0^1x^7dx\\
\end{aligned}\\
&=\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{14}+\frac{1}{15}-\frac{1}{24}\\
&=\frac{3}{56}\\
\end{align}$$
But in my book the answer is:$\frac{\pi}{4}$. Can you please tell my fault?

Comment: Your calculation is absolutely correct, and the answer in the book is wrong (provided that you correctly cited both the problem and the answer).

Comment: Thank you for this confirmation 